# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError but .class file already exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using Maven and Tomcat for web development. I got the following error message:

> Error message:" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /api/core/dto/IDTO " .

However, `IDTO.class` already exists in the folder as:

[/api/core/dto/IDTO.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPBDH.png)

I checked several answers about `NoClassDefFoundError`, they all say about wrong `PATH` on runtime. What goes wrong? Why did I get the Exception?

Comment: Check your jar files which are download by maven and make sure you download correct jar files

Answer (score 0):

The point is the directory where that image was taken.  It should be:

- If your app is deployed as an open directory in, say, /opt/tomcat/apps/yourapp, should be inside /opt/tomcat/apps/yourapp/WEB-INF/classes/api/core/dto/IDTO.class
- If your app is packed with maven as a .war file, the class file should be in a similar place inside your .war: WEB-INF/classes/api/core/dto/IDTO.class
- If your class is contained on a dependency, say a mylibrary.jar file, you should make sure that the jar is packed inside the war in WEB-INF/lib/mylibrary.jar.  Inside the jar file the class should be found in a path equal to its fully qualified name: api/core/dto/IDTO.class

If the .jar is not inside the .war file, you should check your pom.xml looking for the dependency, and make sure there is not `<scope>` element in the dependency.  The wrong scope, say for example 'provided', would make the jar not to be packed inside the war.